# Javascript Number Swapping

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create function that takes number as argument as long as its 2 digits and swaps it as example : (24) -> (42)

```
function swapNumber(num) {
    if (num > 9 && num < 100) {
        Math.trunc(num)
         // Continue 
    } else {
        return "Input 2 digit numbers"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Did you try converting it to a string and reversing the string and then parsing it back to a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```js
function swapNumber(num) {
  if (typeof num !== "number") throw new TypeError("Invalid Number");
  num = num.toString();
  num = num.split("");
  num = num.reverse();
  num = num.join("");
  num = Number(num);
  return num;
}
```

That will work for numbers of any length. If you vant only 2-digit numbers add

```js
if (num.length !== 2) throw new TypeError("Number must be two digits only");
```

right after the `num.toString();` line.

Minified versions:

```js
//All numbers
function swapNumber(num){if(typeof num!=="number"){throw new TypeError("Invalid Number");};return Number(num.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));}

//Two digits
function swapNumber(num){if(typeof num!=="number"){throw new TypeError("Invalid Number");};if(num.toString().length !== 2){throw new TypeError("Number must be two digits only");};return Number(num.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```js
function swapNumber(num) {
    num = parseInt(num); // just in case they try 11.2 or something
    if (num > 9 && num < 100) {
        const lastNumber = num % 10;
        const firstNumber = (num - lastNumber) / 10;
        return (lastNumber * 10 + firstNumber)
    } else {
        return "Input 2 digit numbers"
    }
}

console.log(swapNumber(12))
console.log(swapNumber(85))
console.log(swapNumber(21))
```

Answer (score 2):

The 1s to 10s

```
orgnum%10*10
```

The 10s to 1s

```
Math.floor(orgnum/10)
```

Total

```
orgnum%10*10 + Math.floor(orgnum/10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that works with any whole number:

```
function swapNumber(num){
  let numStr = "" + num;
  numStr = numStr.split('').reverse().join('');
  return parseInt(numStr, 10);
}
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work reliably. You forgot something very important. In some browsers, `swapNumber(80)` will return `0`. Can you figure out why?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Well I am guessing it has something to do with it starting with 0? Could it be fixed by removing all zeros in string before the first actual digit? Also, which browser exactly doesn't it work in?

Comment: You're on the right track. `parseInt` takes *two* arguments, and the second one is *not* optional. While it's mostly older browsers, some will interpret the missing second argument as "take a guess", then see a number starting with `0` as an octal number. Since `8` is not valid in octal, it gets discarded, leaving just `0`. `parseInt(numStr, 10)` will resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Didn't know that actually, guess we learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use truncate to remove decimals and then covert to string, reverse the string and convert back to number

```
function swapNumber(num) {
let truncatedNum = Math.trunc(num)

if (num > 9 && num < 100) {    
return Number((truncatedNum.toString()).split("").reverse().join(""))
     
} else {
    return "Input 2 digit numbers"
}}
```

Comment: What if I call `swapNumber(12.34)`? You're just *assuming* I'm gonna pass an integer. If you're gonna have checks for range, you should probably check other things too.

Comment: if you only want the 12 to be swapped then output is 21. Math.trunc will remove the decimals

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc

Answer (score 0):

Below Code snippet will do what you require

```js
function reverseNumber(num)
    {
        let revNum = 0;   
        while (num > 0) {
            revNum = revNum * 10 + num % 10;
            num = Math.floor(num / 10);       
        }
        return revNum;
    }
   console.log(reverseNumber(39));
   console.log(reverseNumber(96));
   console.log(reverseNumber(45));
   console.log(reverseNumber(658));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the override symbol from right to left - `\u202E`.

```
'\u202E' + 12 = 21
```

```js
function swapNumber(num) {
    if (num > 9 && num < 100) {
        Math.trunc(num);
        console.log("\u202E" + num);
    } else {
        return "Input 2 digit numbers";
    }
}

swapNumber(12);
```